# Jest failed to parse a file

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

I am using react with typescript, and I just added a new dependency  called react-photoswipe-gallery, and after that my tests are broken, and I get the following error

[image]

my jest.config.js is :

```
module.exports = {
collectCoverage: false,
globals: {
    window: {},
},

moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],
snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
 },
};
```

Comment: try adding this to your jest.conf `transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(react-photoswipe-gallery|photoswipe)/)',
  ],`